# Reloading the specified function from separate files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In file a there is a button that calls the execution of a function from file b and it is removed. Then another button is created that should reset gui to its original state.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to properly configure it to make it work.
In trying to fix it, you ended up with the following errors:

ImportError: cannot import name 'GUI' from partially initialized module 'b' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\user\Desktop\english_app\b.py)
TypeError: back() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'

file a:

```
from tkinter import *
from b import dest
from functools import partial
class Gui:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.b = Button(root, text='destroy', command=partial(dest, root))
        self.b.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Gui(root)
    mainloop()
```

file b:

```
from tkinter import *
class dest:
    def __init__(self, root):
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        self.b_back = Button(root, text="Back", command=self.back)
        self.b_back.pack()

    def back(self, root):
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
       
        Gui(root)
```

Comment: in file b, should it be from a import GUI ?

Comment: Where do you instantiate the dest class?

Comment: Did it fix your error ?

Comment: When I tried to do it, I tried everything that would work and forgot to remove it. Did not work

Comment: How b can use Gui (defined in a) if a imports from b? this will lead to circular dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `import` statement without the `from` to avoid circular imports.
For example:

file a.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import b
from functools import partial
class Gui:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.b = Button(root, text='destroy', command=partial(b.dest, root))
        self.b.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Gui(root)
    mainloop()
```

file b.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import a

class dest:
    def __init__(self, root):
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        self.b_back = Button(root, text="Back", command=self.back(root))
        self.b_back.pack()

    def back(self, root):
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
       
        a.Gui(root)
```

Comment: When I click back, I get the following error: TypeError: back() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'

Comment: Oh that correct, i didn't understand what is the functionality you want in this case but you can fix the Type error by giving root parameter to `self.back(root)` in line 9.         ```self.b_back = Button(root, text="Back", command=self.back(root))```